# Missing functions in sympy.physics.vector

Tags: python, sympy

I want to derive properties like `curl` / `divergence` etc. from a vector/scalar field using a symbolic math library. 
According to the sympy documentation this is possible with the `sympy.physics.vector` module,

http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/vector/api/fieldfunctions.html

http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/vector/fields.html

However I can't find the curl/divergence functions anywhere in this module,
according to the documentation there should be 
`sympy.physics.vector.curl` and `sympy.physics.vector.divergence`

I installed the version with pip and checked the version its 0.7.5. 
So any Ideas where I can find these functions? Maybe the documentation isn't up-to-date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that the docs aren't up-to-date, but that the docs you are looking at are too new. The versions you linked are the git development version of the docs, the `sympy.physics.vector` docs for version 0.7.5 are here:

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/index.html

and you'll see they don't include the "Docstrings for basic field functions", as `sympy.physics.vector.fieldfunctions` is new since 0.7.5. If you wish to use these features, you could install the git development version, you can get instructions for that at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html#git. Otherwise, you'll have to wait for the next SymPy version release.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I guess I will stick to the dev version :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/galgebra/index.html), but I can't pretend that it looks particularly easy to follow. It looks as though the documentation is incomplete (and version 7.0 was different), so you may have to cast around for a while or ask the sympy people directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would describe what you wish to do I could show you how to do it using my new fork of sympy (https://github.com/brombo/sympy) using galgebra.  I can be contacted at abrombo@verizon.net.